# Need gmail to look for sent Label A, then send out canned Label B to "sent recipient"

Tags: gmail

I am no coder, will need help on this. Can anyone help? 
a. a spreadsheet has been programmed to send the first email out.
b. next, I'll need gmail to find that sent email with Label A
c. send out the 2nd email with Label B.

Thanks again.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Regarding your question, what have you tried already? What specific errors you get when trying to solve this? You can't simply expect other users to write your code for you.

Comment: Thank you Gray,

I am still trying to get these few lines to be error-free, before I post up. My intent, is to ask for some ideas on how to sequence these lines, before going into detailed discussion. Will post what I have, shortly.